# Why exchanges show Bitcoin price higher than actual value?

Tags: buy-bitcoins, currencies, cryptography, ethereum

I trade crypto on indian platform WazirX and CoinSwitch. Both are currently showing price of 1 Bitcoin to be 44,78,353 Indian Rupees ($ 60,605.51) while the price shown on google as well as Binance right now is only 41,37,198.19 Indian Rupees ($ 56,000.78) . Same for other crypto. Could someone please explain this huge difference in pricing, I would really appreciate it ?

Comment: to always remain profitable and also to charge fees.

Comment: Price on all exchanges don't need to be same. Price is decided by traders(buyers and sellers) on an exchange which is using open orderbook. There can always be premium or discount on Indian exchanges or price difference between different Indian or any exchanges which provides few arbitrage opportunities for traders sometimes. Also consider fees and everything involved while comparing the difference in price. And I don't see much difference right now.